# Vue Ckeditor content not WYSIWYG

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm using ckeditor for vue js following this [article](https://blowstack.com/blog/frameworks/ckeditor-5-nuxt-integration)
but editor not displaying content correctly (not wysiwyg), text not formatting. Same problem if I use [vue-wysiwyg](https://github.com/chmln/vue-wysiwyg). So I think problem with my vue not wysiwyg tools
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, problem from tailwindcss base theme. "[List are unstyled](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight)"

Add style to tailwind config file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

best way:
install typography

## Using npm

```
npm install @tailwindcss/typography
```

## Using Yarn

```
yarn add @tailwindcss/typography
```

Then add the plugin to your tailwind.config.js file:

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    // ...
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    // ...
  ],
}
```

Now you can use the prose classes to add sensible typography styles to any vanilla HTML:

```html
<article class="prose">
  <h1>Garlic bread with cheese: What the science tells us</h1>

<ul>
   <li>test1</li>
   <li>test2</li>
</ul>
  <!-- ... -->
</article>
```

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-typography